# How to make a VM use AMD IOMMU so I can use a 2nd Graphics card?

Tags: virtualization

This is related to my [question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85776/what-is-iommu-how-can-i-use-it-with-virtualbox-and-will-it-improve-my-vm-perf), However I didn't get the answer of how to Implement it in a VM only of what it was.

Having read that I have a 2nd Graphics card that I don't use, How (if possible) can i make a VM that could make use of that card through the IOMMU feature in my motherboard chipset.

The chipset is an AMD 990X, the 2nd card is an nVidia 8600GT and the Motherboard is an ASUS M5A99xEVO (the first one, as there's a R2.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use VirtualBox, like in your question earlier. However you may want to try KVM. They have a [How-to on that topic](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM). I did a quick search on if the M5A99x EVO and its BIOS supports IOMMU and it looks promising, may be you need a BIOS update.

Comment: Already have the latest BIOS :P , yeah I'd prefer if it was Vbox however as you say KVM or Xen for instance apparently can do it, however I wouldn't know how to use it in those too or in Vbox for that matter, so I'm open to whichever software works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this isn't stable/working completely in virtualbox.  [Here's the ticket where they talk about experimental host bus passthrough](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5252).

This wouldn't work for pcie or getting cuda support in the guest though.  For something like that you're stuck with Xen/KVM/VMWare(I hear they have it working, but I haven't witnessed it directly).

Comment: Yep I stumbled across that ticket too, only network cards seems to be able to use it.